# How to make text width in a pseudo-hint (tooltip)?

Tags: html, css, tooltip

The width of the container should be the length of the text. 
So that the text does not wrap until the maximum width is reached.

`white-space: nowrap;` - not fit.

[For now](https://jsfiddle.net/pL2q7ezo/). 
[Ready sample](http://s27.znimg.ru/1580829420/7svnngszbl.png).

```css
[data-title] {position: relative;}
[data-title]:hover::after {visibility: visible; opacity: 1; transition: all 0.1s ease 0.5s;}
[data-title]::after {
   content: attr(data-title);
   position: absolute;
   left: 100%;
   z-index: 1000001;
   visibility: hidden;
   opacity: 0;

   font: normal 13px/1.3 "Segoe UI", helvetica, arial, sans-serif; 
   color: #000; 
   padding: 2px 5px 3px 5px;
   letter-spacing: -0.01em;
   word-spacing: -0.07em;

   border:1px solid #777; 
   border-radius:2px; 
   box-shadow:5px 5px 3px -2px rgba(0,0,0,0.35);
   background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255,255,255,1) 0%, rgba(222,222,222,1) 100%);

   max-width: 600px; 
   white-space: normal;   
   word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<a href="" data-title="Short text">Tooltip 1</a><br /><br />
<a href="" data-title="Tooltip text about 50 characters long">Tooltip 2</a><br /><br />
<a href="" data-title="The text for this tooltip can exceed 100 characters. The width of the container is limited by the max-width parameter, and the tooltip text should be automatically wrapped.">Tooltip 3</a>
```

Comment: Change `white-space: normal; ` to `white-space: nowrap; ` in the pseudo-element....but it will **never** wrap if you do that. You have to pick *one*, either it wraps or it doesn't.

Comment: @Paulie_D, The `white-space` property - is not the main thing. It can be deleted. The main thing is to solve the problem as in the finished example.

Comment: Pretty sure you can't do this as is. Either you set an actual width or settle for no wrapping.

Comment: @Paulie_D, In pseudo-element. Minus `margin-right` to the desired `max-width`. Сurrently working.. [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u1fv502L/2/)